# Design a label like described in css/xml for NativeScript application

Tags: html, css, xml, label, nativescript

I want to design a label where it's background is a yellow line in the background (over the complete screen) and the text should start after a distance of 30 to the left. I tried the margin-left: 30 which pretty much does what I want for the text, but the background is also moved (and starts right in front of the text).

Can I manipulate the label in a way where only the text is moved and the background starts right from the very left side of the screen and goes to the right side of the screen? I have tried to do research on this but I do not really know how to describe properly what I am looking for (you might have noticed).

Does anyone have a keyword or a pattern for me?

The html:

```
<label text="{{ user_firstname }}" class="label-content" ></label>
```

The css for it:

```
.label-content {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20;
    margin-left: 10;
    margin-right: 10;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 35;
}
```

Edit: I added the html and css code for it.

Comment: Can you add your html and css please. This will help people assist you with a solution.

Comment: Sure, did not think that these would be interesting for the solution at all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin puts space round the element
Padding puts space inside the element wrapping it's content.

So change your "margin" to "padding"

```
.label-content {
    padding-bottom: 20;
    padding-left: 10;
    padding-right: 10;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 35;
}
```